# What does "-pa" on the command line mean, if anything?

Tags: command-line, erlang, installation

I am trying to play around with erlubi, a bit of software written to visualise erlang processes:

[erlubi (github)](https://github.com/krestenkrab/erlubi)

One of the steps in the setup instructions is as follows:

```
 "Run erlang with -pa erlubi/ebin -pa erlubi/deps/xmlrpc/ebin on the command line"
```

My terminal does not recognise the "-pa" command and I find no mention using search engines. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the man page:

> -pa Dir1 Dir2 ... :
>     Adds the specified directories to the beginning of the code path, similar to code:add_pathsa/1 .

Basically, it enables erlang to use the compiled files in that directory

Comment: Many thanks, However I cannot find the man page. (e.g. typing 'man pa' in xterm). How/where did you access the man page?

Comment: @atomh33ls `-pa` is a erlang flag, not an individual command; you should check the erlang man page (`man erl`). well, if somehow you don't have it, it can be found here: http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html (btw you should run erlubi as `erl -pa erlubi/ebin...`)

Comment: `-pa` => *path add*.